# Simple graphing software

Tags: graphs

I'm looking for a software for creating visual graphs of connected nodes. Specifically, what I need is to be able to: create named containers, populate them with named items, and draw lines between the items. Most of the software I find is UML graphing software, and this is a level of complexity I don't need.

Comment: Are you after a software that allows you to manually draw the graph, the nodes and lines yourself, or a software that can generate the image of the graph from a text file that describes the nodes and relationships? I've used https://graphviz.org/ to generate images of the graphs from text descriptions.

Comment: Maybe [Paint.net](https://www.getpaint.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is to use https://draw.io/ (have also standalone version to be installed/portable). It offer sample but powerful interface for making different diagrams. Also exist option to extend by plugins and additional diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I used [graphviz](https://Graphviz.org) library, but I remember there was some tools and command to produce graphs.

You will find a lot of tools and resources using this library on the
[ressource page](https://graphviz.org/resources).

It also exist a library named [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) that may cover your needs (requiring a bit of javascript to reach a good result).

Reading your question it seems that you'd like to create a [Family Tree](https://graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/kennedyanc.html). Anyway, take a look at the [gallery](https://graphviz.org/gallery/).

I Hope it help.